# python regex to print previous words in text file

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I have a text file where i need to print its previous word.the text file contains as:

```
Sparrow=beak
Hen=nest Honey=comb
```

I need to output as:

```
Sparrow
Hen
Honey
```

Coding:

```
import re

with open('qwert.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        res = re.findall(r'(?:=(\w-))', line)
        if res: 
            print res
```

I am not getting output,please help!

Answer (score 1):

Using postiive lookahead assertion `(?=...)`:

```
import re

with open('qwert.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for res in re.findall(r'\w+(?==\w)', line):
            # Match word characters (`\w+`) followed by `=` and word character.
            print res
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string format is kinda strict, you can use split which not only get you keys, but also values.

```
line = "Hen=nest Honey=comb"
keys = [key for key, value in [token.split('=') for token in line.split(' ')]]
```

Then just print keys out.